# Sort text with number as prefix within a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's say I want to generate a product name following the composition of raw materials.
AA, BB, CC, DD, EE and FF are the components.
50, 100, 8, 12, 1 and 2 are the quantities.

[image: Screenshot of Excel sheet]

To get a name with the most present component at the begining, I would like to sort ascending the data inside cells S1 and S3.

The formula I founded works pretty well, but it's more complicated when I have a number below 10.

Formula in S1:

```
=CONCAT(
INDEX(M1:R1;1;EQUIV(PETITE.VALEUR(NB.SI(M1:R1;"<"&M1:R1);1);NB.SI(M1:R1;"<"&M1:R1);0));
" ";
INDEX(M1:R1;1;EQUIV(PETITE.VALEUR(NB.SI(M1:R1;"<"&M1:R1);2);NB.SI(M1:R1;"<"&M1:R1);0));
" ";
INDEX(M1:R1;1;EQUIV(PETITE.VALEUR(NB.SI(M1:R1;"<"&M1:R1);3);NB.SI(M1:R1;"<"&M1:R1);0));
" ";
INDEX(M1:R1;1;EQUIV(PETITE.VALEUR(NB.SI(M1:R1;"<"&M1:R1);4);NB.SI(M1:R1;"<"&M1:R1);0));
" ";
INDEX(M1:R1;1;EQUIV(PETITE.VALEUR(NB.SI(M1:R1;"<"&M1:R1);5);NB.SI(M1:R1;"<"&M1:R1);0));
" ";
INDEX(M1:R1;1;EQUIV(PETITE.VALEUR(NB.SI(M1:R1;"<"&M1:R1);6);NB.SI(M1:R1;"<"&M1:R1);0)))
```

Do you think there is a workaround to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Instead (or at least in addition to) providing us a link to an excel file please post an image and the code you use here. This way this question will still hold relevance after your link will stop working in 29 days.

Comment: @DarkDiamond Thanks, I updated my initial post!

Comment: @BlindSpots The source data is generated manually. Columns A, C, E, G, I and K are permanent, and the user change the other ones with the quantities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, someone ([Credit](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1395680-sort-text-with-number-as-prefix-within-a-cell.html)) gave me the solution!

In S1, we can use this formula:

```
=LET(t;TRIER(ORGA.LIGNES(A1:L1;2);2;-1);f;INDEX(t;;2);JOINDRE.TEXTE(" ";;FILTRE(f&INDEX(t;;1);f>0)))
```

That answer perfectly my needs.

Thanks!